# How do you get a / into a filename?

Tags: unix

How do you get a / into a filename 
(i.e., a / that doesn't separate components of the path)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't. Slashes are not allowed in UNIX filenames.

Comment: Short. Succinct. Correct. I can't compete with that. +1. Of course, you could edit the directory files themselves but only $DEITY knows what havoc that would cause.

Comment: If one is only interested in the approximate look, then U+2044, U+2215 or U+FF0F might be options. But I think this would be considerably frowned upon by UNIX people.

Comment: Yes, it would be frowned upon. I still hunt down people who use spaces in their file names and beat them senseless with a wet stick of celery (takes a while but it's enjoyable). Unicode characters would make me livid. :-)

Comment: Reminds me of my favorite unix-noob haze: cd; echo >"-r -f *" ... just be kind and backup there home directory first.

Comment: @corlettk: this is why I have files called "-i" in strategic positions on my fs

Comment: The reason why i asked this question at all is:
This is a question on page 79 in the book "the unix programming environment"

the only way i can think of is to mess up with the directory entries    
in the disk block device.

however, since the authors stated clearly this was a trick question.
i assume there's a smarter solution.

Comment: By "trick question" I think they meant there isn't a solution.

Comment: you're probably right.
it reminds me of one of interview questions
"write a function/method to swap two integers in java"